# Drools- how to get the facts which trigered the rule?

Tags: jboss, drools, rule-engine

I have a lot of events log insert to ksession, and I need to find out the facts which trigered the specific rule.How can i get the relation ship between the facts which trigered the rule and the events log?

Comment: Please add java code for exact answer.

Comment: Have you tried adding an agenda event listener, perhaps? Please show your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `drools` keyword

```
import java.util.Arrays;

rule
when
    ...
then
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(drools.getTuple().toObjects()));
    ...
end
```